# Generate Native Access Fails

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I am using Codename One trying to provide a way in my app to access the device mfg name and model number through a native interface. I watched the tutorial and it seems easy enough however I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I right click on the interface and choose "Generate Native Access". I have tried a clean/compile and I still get the error. Can anyone out there provide any info on what this might be? Here is the full stack trace:

> IllegalName: com/tsi/gpflow/NativeDeviceInfo
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: com/tsi/gpflow/NativeDeviceInfo
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:654)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at com.codename1.plugin.intellij.actions.GenerateNativeAccessAction$1.buildFinished(GenerateNativeAccessAction.java:51)
>       at com.intellij.lang.ant.config.execution.AntBuildMessageView$6$1$1$1.run(AntBuildMessageView.java:819)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEventsInWriteAction(RefreshSessionImpl.java:233)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl$1$1.run(RefreshSessionImpl.java:196)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1009)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl$1.run(RefreshSessionImpl.java:193)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEvents(RefreshSessionImpl.java:206)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl$1$1.run(RefreshQueueImpl.java:93)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a bug there. Unfortunately it seems we only tested this feature on Macs and some idiot (me) used `File.separator` instead of using the `/` symbol. We'll fix that in the next plugin update which should be out Friday (hopefully).

Comment: Sounds good thank you for the response. I'll try again after the upgrade comes out.

Comment: I updated to the latest version today (3.4.5) and creating the native interface works however now when I actually go to use it in code NativeLookup.create is returning null. I placed a break point in the create method and interfaceToClassLookup is null indicating the register method is never called. I tried finding other places where its used so I can call it manually but I cant fine any. I know the first parameter is the interface.class I created but I'm not sure what to pass in as the second parameter.

Comment: Now that I have looked at it more I see in the comments for the create method that it will return null "if the native interface isn't present on the underlying platform (e.g. simulator platform)." I'm assuming that means it will return null when running it on the simulator. Is that correct? That would explain it since I was running it on the simulator.

Comment: Yes it can be null and will be null in some cases, however that still seems to be a problem. The JavaSE version of the classes should be loaded for the simulator. It's possible the classpath isn't set correctly during the build and there are quite a few nuances involved here. I filed an issue for this https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1830